# TypeError on Electron's example using Webdriver's client.init()

Tags: javascript, electron, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I'm attempting to set up an E2E test suite for an Electron application running on electron@5.0.2. I've tried using spectron, but am continuously running into problems with `waitUntilWindowLoaded()` and receiving information from the DOM. This seems to be a consistent issue with the spectron framework, so instead of waiting for that to be resolved, I thought I would try using webdriverio, since electron has a nice [example](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver#setting-up-with-webdriverio) on their page. I'm having issues with this example as well though.

I did as was suggested in the first two steps and pasted the code provided in the new project.

```
const webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
const options = {
   host: 'localhost',
   port: 9515,
   desiredCapabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      chromeOptions: {
         binary: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Our App\\Our App.exe',
      },
   },
};

let client = webdriverio.remote(options);

client.init().getTitle().then(function(title) {
   console.log('Title: ' + title);
});
```

And the current dependencies, some I grabbed during troubleshooting:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "@types/node": "^12.6.9",
   "@wdio/cli": "^5.11.13",
   "electron-chromedriver": "^6.0.0",
   "wdio": "^3.0.3",
   "webdriverio": "^5.11.12"
}
```

Currently, I'm getting stopped by `client.init()`. The exact error is `TypeError: client.init is not a function`. What is causing this error and how do I resolve it?

Comment: I think `webdriverio.remote(...)` returns a`Promise`. Try `let client = await webdriverio.remote(...);` (you'll have to wrap this in an `async` function).

Comment: @Titus - Well, now I'm getting `(node:10396) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Required option "capabilities" is missing`. I wrapped the `let` and `client.init()` lines together to avoid scope issues, then called the function.

Comment: Based on the error message it seems that the `options` object needs a `capabilities` property. Try to replace `desiredCapabilities` with `capabilities`. At least that is how the example in the [documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/setuptypes.html) looks like.

Comment: @Titus - changed that, now it's erroring on `chromeOptions` and I can't seem to find an equivalent for it or for `binary` to tell it to run the app instead of chromedriver. Checked [here](https://webdriver.io/docs/options.html#capabilities) for the short example and [here](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#capabilities) for more detailed options available for `capabilities`.